# Blender's internal pack margin is inconsistent

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I am wondering if it is possible to calculate the packing margin needed for the pack uvs operator of a specific pixel width?

I would like a pixel margin of 2 for a 256 by 256 texture.
Unfortunately, it seems the margin changes not just based on this margin value, but the size and/or number of islands.

I am aware of UV-packmaster and UVPacker3, which do what I'm requesting, but both have externally referenced proprietary code, so I think people will benefit from an internal solution.

Here is what I've found texturing with basic cube faces:

[image]

Comment: So what is your question? - This is a Q&A site run by volunteers to help answer questions about problems using Blender and its built-in addons. There are no Blender developers here and no-one here has any connection with the Blender Foundation.

Comment: Hi @JohnEason. My question is "I am wondering, firstly if it is possible to calculate the packing margin needed for this operator. I would like a pixel margin for 2x256 texture." Sorry if that was not clear.

Comment: You'll have to ask the developers that one!

Comment: Gotcha. Thank you